# How to change value in pandas based on some conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following types of pandas data frame

```
    ID  pp
0   1   1
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   2   0
4   2   0
5   2   0
6   3   1
7   3   1
8   3   1
9   3   1
10  4   0
```

Here for unique `ID` value the `pp`  value are the same, but
I want to replace  `pp` column value "1" with "0" where it is'not last one for unique ID.
For example for `ID= 1` its `pp` is `1` everywhere, but I want to replace this `1` with `0` except the last value for ID=1. For the last value where ID=1 I want to leave pp=1
Here is what I want to have:

```
ID  pp
0   1   0
1   1   0
2   1   1
3   2   0
4   2   0
5   2   0
6   3   0
7   3   0
8   3   0
9   3   1
10  4   0
```

Comment: *want to replace pp column value "1" with "0" where it is last one for unique ID* - can you explain this statement? its not very clear

Comment: @anky I edit this one

Comment: Why does index 9 get 0 for ID=3? it is one in the input

Comment: @anky yes, there where mistake

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a condition with df.duplicated keep=last , and check if  pp=1 , then assign 0 to the elements where condition matches else df['pp'] using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
c = (df.duplicated(['ID','pp'],keep='last')) & df['pp'].eq(1)
df['pp'] = np.where(c,0,df['pp'])
```

---

```
print(df)
    ID  pp
0    1   0
1    1   0
2    1   1
3    2   0
4    2   0
5    2   0
6    3   0
7    3   0
8    3   0
9    3   1
10   4   0
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4]
   , 'pp':[1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]
   }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['ID_offset'] = df['ID'].shift(-1)
df.loc[df['ID']==df['ID_offset'],"pp"]=0
df.loc[df['ID']!=df['ID_offset'],"pp"]=1
df.drop(['ID_offset'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df
```